# How many images can be shown on a notification in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, unnotificationattachment

How many images can be shown on a notification in iOS 10?

I've appended two images to the UNNotificationContent.attachments attribute in my UNNotificationServiceExtension. I only see one in the remote notification. Is there anyway to display more than one?

If no then, how does iOS 10 decide which ones to use in the notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can attach multiple attachments in rich notifications. So answering your questions.

**Which one comes first?**
Whatever that has small size and downloads first, that will come.

**Why might you get issue?**
There will be one completion handler. We have to finish our downloading process before 30secs. Whatever that downloads before 30 secs will be shown and the rest of the things will be discarded. So this might be the case of yours. I'm just assuming it. But I'm not sure of the exact issue of yours. So please make sure that you are not downloading Big size files which take more than 30 secs to load.

Comment: I printed out the size of the attachments. It says 2. But only 1 image is shown on the remote notification.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and my service extension is definitely hitting the completion, not the expiration with 3 attachments. The content extension is only receiving a notification with 1 attachment.

Comment: Are you setting category identifier?

Comment: Please look at this. It might be helpful https://docs.carnival.io/docs/ios-rich-push